# How to efficiently retrieve the count of unique values in a GridDB column?

Tags: database, griddb

I'm working with **GridDB,** a distributed NoSQL database, and I have a specific requirement where I need to retrieve the count of unique values in a column within a GridDB container. The column contains a large number of values, and I'm looking for an efficient approach to perform this operation.
I have attempted to use the COUNT DISTINCT SQL function in GridDB to achieve this, but I've noticed that it can be quite slow, especially when dealing with large datasets. I have also considered creating an index on the column to improve performance, but the improvement has been minimal.
To provide more context, I'm using the GridDB C API to interact with the database. I have a container named "myContainer" with a column named "myColumn" that contains string values. I need to find the count of unique values in "myColumn" efficiently.
Here's an example of the query I'm currently using:

const char* query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT myColumn) FROM myContainer";

I'm seeking suggestions on alternative approaches or GridDB-specific optimizations that can help improve the performance of retrieving the count of unique values in a GridDB column. Are there any specific GridDB APIs or functions that can assist in achieving this more efficiently? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time and expertise!